# Is there an application that can manipulate images for ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Basically functionality i need is:

1. easy integration with ASP.NET application.
2. user ability to crop image with handle prior to save
3. image optimization from any image type to jpg (compression levels) during the save
4. saving images with proper h/w ratios during the save
5. user ability to rotate the image prior to save
6. ability to translate application to foreign language as it won't be used on international site

If you know any application which fits my needs even if it costs money, give me a twit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found exactly what i was looking for [iLoad](http://i-load.radactive.com/)

Does exactly what i asked and doesn't cost that much compared to other suggested solutions. Haven't tried it yet but demo is impressive.

Comment: The demos do look pretty decent.

Comment: Sadly this has now been discontinued, which is why I'm hear researching alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Our company has implemented a photo cropper in an ASP.Net MVC application using Atalasoft's DotImage.  I did not implement this myself, but I currently maintain the whole of that application (and consequently the cropping component).

Based on the way you phrased your question, I feel that I should explicitly point out that Atalasoft's DotImage only provided the functionality to manipulate images.  Other answers referenced ImageMagick and GDI+.  In the same vein, these libraries also only provide the functionality to manipulate images.

We had to implement the UI and workflow ourselves.  This was, while not rocket science, still far from trivial.  While we used a pre-built component for fancy, AJAX-y file uploads (for the source photos) - we still had to integrate that into the application and manage persistence of the files and database records associated with them.  (Similarly, as a convenience we allow import photo from url - another feature we had to explicitly create)

I would suggest that you will not find any general purpose component to integrate that will give you cropping functionality and a Web UI.  I suppose there may be one made by a ASP.Net component vendor, but I am certainly not aware of any off-hand.

The problem tends to involve lots of pieces that span from the client to the server, and consequently I think what you are looking for will involve a fair amount of specific-to-your-application development and integration.

Comment: thanks. Your answer is probably the only answer than fits my question. Next time i will try to ask better question to get proper answers and not like above.

Anyway, DotImage doesn't have all functionality i asked and does costs lots more than application i've found.

Comment: @eugeneK it does support all the image manipulations you mentioned in your question, but I agree it won't do everything you seem to want.  And yes, it is quite expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), it supports hundreds of image formats and it comes with a .NET wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [mcImageManager](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_imagemanager.php)